# Connect to Multichain network using aws EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, bitcoin, blockchain

I am trying to learn basics of blockchain by trying the multichain platform, I have been following multichain guide to make a private blockchain, I am using two instances of EC2, I managed to create a blockchain using my first instance :

```
>multichaind secondChain -daemon

MultiChain Core Daemon build 1.0 alpha 27 protocol 10007

MultiChain server starting
Looking for genesis block...
Genesis block found

Other nodes can connect to this node using:
multichaind secondChain@XXX.XX.X.XX:XXXX

Node started
```

However, when I try to connect to the blockchain using a second instance of EC2, I am getting rejected :

```
>multichaind secondChain@XXX.XX.X.XX:XXXX

MultiChain Core Daemon build 1.0 alpha 27 protocol 10007

Retrieving blockchain parameters from the seed node XXX.XX.X.XX:XXXX ...
Error: Couldn't connect to the seed node XXX.XX.X.XX on port XXXX - please check multichaind is running at that address and that your firewall settings allow incoming connections.
```

Which is kind of expected, as I need to grant connect rights to that machine. However, It should return me a wallet address so I can grant the connection rights.

I think this is related to EC2 settings that are probably not allowing me to connect. I have few knowledge of EC2 and networks in general. I can't figure this out.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Bitcoin Stack Exchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if the access to the port is granted on the instance you're trying to connect?

Answer (score 0):

If multichaind says "please check multichaind is running at that address and that your firewall settings allow incoming connection"

It is usually one or the other. Port and Running already.
Since you havent yet granted, its probably port.